# tensor product of a number field with $ \mathbb R $

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a number field, i.e. a finite extension of the field of rational numbers $ \mathbb Q .$ And consider the tensor product:

$$ K \otimes_{\mathbb Q } \mathbb R $$

I have the questions:

> 1. Why is it a real vector space ?
> 2. What's the form of the canonical embedding $ K \hookrightarrow K \otimes_{\mathbb Q } \mathbb R  $ ?

I am not very familiar with the tensor products. I came up with this question in a different context.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the first question? One defines $\lambda \cdot x \otimes y := x \otimes \lambda y$

Comment: @menag: I see...i totally forgot about it. Thank's!